# MSBuildWorkspace.OpenSolutionAsync throws an Exception

Tags: c#, .net, roslyn

Here is the complete code:

```
MSBuildWorkspace msBuild = MSBuildWorkspace.Create();
Solution sln = await msBuild.OpenSolutionAsync(solutionPath);//NullReferenceException
```

where `solutionPath` is a valid **.sln** Visual Studio 2015 solution. I tried both a Winforms new project and a dll with a simple class. I closed that solution before attempting to read it, but that didn't help. It still throws the NullReferenceException.
I'm using VS2015. x64 Windows 10.

Is `MSBuildWorkspace` the wrong kind of `Workspace`? Is something else missing?

<sub>(NullReferenceException is actually a strange error to be thrown by a method. This is usually the type of error thrown by something like mistakenNull.DoSomething(); .)</sub>

**EDIT 2** - This code is in a dll project in a solution which also contains a simple Winforms project which calls this code. (Since the Roslyn project template created a dll project.) Perhaps this matters.

---

### **EDIT - Stack Trace**

**The exception**: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

**Stack Trace**:

```
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.GetReferences(CSharpCompilerInputs compilerInputs, ProjectInstance executedProject, IEnumerable`1& metadataReferences, IEnumerable`1& analyzerReferences)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.CreateProjectFileInfo(CSharpCompilerInputs compilerInputs, ProjectInstance executedProject)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.CSharpProjectFileLoader.CSharpProjectFile.<GetProjectFileInfoAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<LoadProjectAsync>d__40.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<GetOrLoadProjectAsync>d__39.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.MSBuild.MSBuildWorkspace.<OpenSolutionAsync>d__34.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at namespace1.RosTest.<RenameMethods>d__0.MoveNext() in C:\Users\...
```

Comment: _"Is something else missing?"_ -- well, a fair amount of important detail, to start with. At the very least, you need to provide the full stack trace for the exception. Beyond that, take a moment to think about whether those two lines of code are literally _all_ that is needed for a third party to independently reproduce the problem. You are much more likely to get a good, useful answer if you have provided enough context for others to fully understand the question.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks. a) I thought that these lines **are** enough to reproduce the error, and that I'm missing some other obvious lines. b) Added Stack Trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure include `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll` and or `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces.dll` beside your application.

The workspaces code loads them dynamically.

Comment: Both are referenced, and also `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.VisualBasic.Workspaces.dll` which is probably what you meant.

Comment: This code is in a dll project in a solution which also has a simple Winforms project which calls this code. (Since the Roslyn project template created a dll project.) Perhaps this matters.

Comment: Update: Though `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll` _is_ referenced - adding a using directive to that namespace fails: `using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces;` - `The type or namespace name 'Workspaces' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Comment: There are no public types in Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll, so the using statement error is expected.  Even though it is *referenced*, it won't be copied to the output directory unless used unless you force it to be.  Can you verify that bin\debug directory of your winforms app has the dll present?

Comment: I believe it is copying: his stack already shows the CSharpProjectFileLoader is present.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski (and Kevin, but you'll be notified anyway) The bin/debug contains `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.dll` and `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.dll` (and many more) but _not_ `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Workspaces.dll`. Is that the problem? If so - why doesn't it? It is referenced like all the others.

Comment: The C# compiler doesn't emit that a DLL references another DLL unless you actually use directly a type from it. Since we're loading through reflection, that doesn't happen. If MSBuild somewhere else in your process notices this, it won't get copied.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski Thanks. So how do I tell it to copy it?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski (and Kevin...) I copied it manually now, and the exception is gone. So thank you very much, both of you. (I still, tough, would like a way of making Visual Studio copy it.)

Comment: Was CopyLocal = true set in the UI? What happens if you explicitly add <Private>true</Private> as metadata to the file reference?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski CopyLocal is true. Perhaps that only copies it to the folder bin/debug of the dll project (where it is actually copied automatically). (By the way - if you don't "@ispiro" me - I'm not notified of your comment.)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this got resolved when I installed the correct version of 
"Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp" assembly from the below link.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp/

This may help someone, so am posting here.